# which of the following statement is True

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function.
which of the following statement is True

$(1)$ $f( \bar  z)$ is holomorphic;

$(2)$ Suppose that $f(\mathbb{R}) ⊆ \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathbb{R};$

$(3)$ the map $z \rightarrow e^{f(z)}$ is holomorphic;

$(4)$ Suppose that $f(\mathbb{C}) ⊂ \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ for every closed subset $A$ of $\mathbb{C}.$

## Attempts  :

option  $1)$  will be  True  by cauchy reimann equation

option $2)$  will be false  take  $f(x) = 0$

option $3)$  will be True  take $f(z) = z$

option $4)$  will be  false $ f(z) =  e^ z$

Is  my answer  is correct ?

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: You can't prove $(3)$ in full generality by just exhibiting an example. If you were to prove it, you should see that $e^f$ is holomorphic for any $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is  false. If $f(z)=z$ then $f(\overset {-} z)$ is not holomorphic. (C-R equations do not hold).

For 2) your answer is correct.

3) is true because for every holomorphic function $f$ the function $e^{f}$ is also holomorphic.

4)If $f(\mathbb C) \subset \mathbb R$ them we can show that $f$ is a constant function. (You can use C-R equation to show this). Hence 4) is true.

Details for 4): let $u$ and $v$ be the real and imaginary parts of $f$. Then $v\equiv 0$. Hence both partial derivatives of $v$ are $0$. C-R equations now show that partial derivatives of $u$ are also $0$. This makes $u$ a constant, so $f=u+i0$ is also a constant.

Answer (score 2):

- The answer in $(1)$ is not correct. Taking $f$ to be the identity, we get that $f(\bar{z}) = \bar{z}$ which is **not** holomorphic.
- The second one is correct, as $f( \mathbb{R}) = \{0\}$ is not open in the reals.
- Statement $(3)$ is correct but, as I have commented, for the *wrong reasons*. You should see that every such $f$ verifies it. Indeed, this follows from the fact that $e^z$ is holomorphic and composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic.
- As for $(4)$, note that the image of $e^z$ is **not** contained in the reals: for example, 
  $$
  e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = i.
  $$ 
  However, the result is true because of the following argument: if $f$ is constantly $c$, then the image of *any* set is $\{c\}$ which is closed. But there is no other option: since $f$ is entire, if it were non-constant then Picard's theorem assures that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. However, $\mathbb{R}$ is not dense on the complex plane, and so $f$ must be constant.